# i have some problem about how calling the method from another CPP class in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, header, header-files

```
int main()
{
    HeapTree* root = NULL;
    HeapTree object;
    ifstream myFileStream("kisi.txt");
    if (!myFileStream.is_open())
    {
        cout << "kisi.txt dosyasi bulunamadi" << endl;
    }
    string isim, yass, kiloo, line;
    int yas, kilo;
    while (getline(myFileStream, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, isim, '#');
        getline(ss, yass, '#');
        getline(ss, kiloo, '#');
        stringstream ss2(yass);
        ss2 >> yas;
        stringstream ss3(kiloo);
        ss3 >> kilo;
        yas = 2020 - yas;
        root = insert(root, yas, kilo, isim);//here is my problem i cant call insert
    }

    myFileStream.close();

    object.postOrder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

```
#ifndef HEAPTREE_HPP
#define HEAPTREE_HPP
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

class HeapTree
{
public:
    int key;
    HeapTree* left;
    HeapTree* right;
    int height;
    int yas;
    int kilo;
    string isim;
    stack <char> s;
    int max(int a, int b);
    HeapTree* insert(HeapTree*, int, int, string);
    void postOrder(HeapTree*);
    ~HeapTree();

};
#endif
```

```
#include "HEAPTREE.hpp"

int height(HeapTree* N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return N->height;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

HeapTree* newNode(int key, int kilo, string isim)
{
    HeapTree* Heaptree = new HeapTree();
    Heaptree->key = key;
    Heaptree->left = NULL;
    Heaptree->right = NULL;
    Heaptree->height = 1;
    Heaptree->s.push('O');
    Heaptree->isim = isim;
    Heaptree->kilo = kilo;

    return(Heaptree);
}


HeapTree* rightRotate(HeapTree* y)
{

    HeapTree* x = y->left;
    HeapTree* T2 = x->right;

    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    int yHeight = y->height;
    int xHeight = x->height;

    y->height = max(height(y->left),
        height(y->right)) + 1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left),
        height(x->right)) + 1;

    if (x->height > xHeight)
        x->s.push('Y');
    else if (x->height < xHeight)
        x->s.push('A');
    else
        x->s.push('D');

    if (y->height > yHeight)
        y->s.push('Y');
    else if (y->height < yHeight)
        y->s.push('A');
    else
        y->s.push('D');

    // Return new root
    return x;
}


HeapTree* leftRotate(HeapTree* x)
{

    HeapTree* y = x->right;
    HeapTree* T2 = y->left;

    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    int yHeight = y->height;
    int xHeight = x->height;

    x->height = max(height(x->left),
        height(x->right)) + 1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left),
        height(y->right)) + 1;

    if (x->height > xHeight)
        x->s.push('Y');
    else if (x->height < xHeight)
        x->s.push('A');
    else
        x->s.push('D');

    if (y->height > yHeight)
        y->s.push('Y');
    else if (y->height < yHeight)
        y->s.push('A');
    else
        y->s.push('D');

    return y;
}


int getBalance(HeapTree* N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(N->left) - height(N->right);
}


HeapTree* insert(HeapTree* HeapTree, int key, int kilo, string isim)
{
    if (HeapTree == NULL)
        return(newNode(key, kilo, isim));

    if (key < HeapTree->key) {
        HeapTree->s.push('Y');
        HeapTree->left = insert(HeapTree->left, key, kilo, isim);
    }
    else if (key > HeapTree->key)
    {
        HeapTree->s.push('A');
        HeapTree->right = insert(HeapTree->right, key, kilo, isim);
    }

    int nHeight = HeapTree->height;
    HeapTree->height = 1 + max(height(HeapTree->left),
        height(HeapTree->right));

    int balance = getBalance(HeapTree);

    if (balance > 1 && key < HeapTree->left->key)
        return rightRotate(HeapTree);

    if (balance < -1 && key > HeapTree->right->key)
        return leftRotate(HeapTree);

    if (balance > 1 && key > HeapTree->left->key)
    {
        HeapTree->left = leftRotate(HeapTree->left);
        return rightRotate(HeapTree);
    }

    if (balance < -1 && key < HeapTree->right->key)
    {
        HeapTree->right = rightRotate(HeapTree->right);
        return leftRotate(HeapTree);
    }

    return HeapTree;
}
void HeapTree::postOrder(HeapTree* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    postOrder(root->left);
    postOrder(root->right);

    cout << root->isim << ", " << 2020 - root->key << ", " << root->kilo << "   ";

    while (!root->s.empty())
    {
        cout << root->s.top() << " ";
        root->s.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
}

HeapTree::~HeapTree() {}
```

This program for Heap Tree i have a problem in main.cpp class about insert method it use it for taking name from txt file and do some operating but my problem is i cant call it from HeapTree.cpp i think should write it in heaptree.hpp to define it i try some way to solve it but i want a professional way to solve it i think its easy problem.
can any one helping me please

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220862/discussion-on-question-by-abdulrahman-al-samaraie-i-have-some-problem-about-how).

Answer (score 1):

When you define your functions in file `HeapTree.cpp`, there is nothing to tell the compiler those functions are members of the class HeapTree, rather than usual functions.

For instance:

```
HeapTree* insert(HeapTree* HeapTree, int key, int kilo, string isim)
{
  ...
}
```

This defines a function called `insert()` that returns a `HeapTree*`. The function `insert()` is not defined as a member of the class HeapTree.

Instead, you should write:

```
HeapTree* HeapTree::insert(HeapTree* HeapTree, int key, int kilo, string isim)
{
  ...
}
```

Notice the extra `HeapTree::` in front of the name of the function. You can add this prefix to the definition of every function in the file `HeapTree.cpp` to tell the compiler that those are not functions, but members of the class HeapTree.

Comment: i tried to put it but it show me another error inside the insert fun.

Comment: @ABDULRAHMANAL-SAMARAIE "_it show me another error_" - Whenever _you_ see an error, please include that error so that people don't have to guess what the error might be.

Comment: I'm guessing the error is because of the argument `HeapTree* HeapTree`. This argument has two obvious problems: 1) you are using the same name for the class and for the variable, which is bound to cause confusion and errors; 2) since `insert()` will now be a member of class `HeapTree`, it will be called as `tree.insert(...)` where `tree` is a variable of class HeapTree. So logically `insert()` doesn't need to take a tree as an argument. It will already be called as the member function of a given tree.